# How to cite in latex using references.bib

Tags: citing

I am trying to cite my references in latex using my reference details which are stored in the file references.bib. I referenced as \cite{blah} but it does not work. Does it need some package?

[image]

Comment: You've tagged this biblatex, so yes, this needs `biblatex`. Otherwise, if you use bibtex, you need no package, but have you run bibtex (or in case of biblatex biber)? If you've run this and checked that you've specified the right file in your TeX, please post a minimal compilable example here (MWE).

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question please go back to your previous question and accept an answer if one of those solved your problem.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for your comment. I am working in TeXstudio. I changed the tag. Now do I need any package?

By the way, about my previous question, both the answers were useful, however did not solve my problem. I used something else to solve the problem and I mentioned that in the comments. I really do not know what to so in this case!

Comment: Can you show us your code? Are you running BibTeX or biber? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/117534 as this is a faq

Comment: @Troy  I found the solution using the link that you put. Thanks!